# How runCommand geohaystack use > < <= >= to format properly

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I run this query in mongo shell

```
db.runCommand({ geoSearch : "tablebusiness", near : [106.90, -6.20], maxDistance : 0.053980478460939611, search : { "Prominent" :  15 }, limit : 20 });
```

And  I got result.

But when I run this query

```
db.runCommand({ geoSearch : "tablebusiness", near : [106.90, -6.20], maxDistance : 0.053980478460939611, search : { "Prominent" : {gte: 15} }, limit : 20 });
```

I got nothing result.

So How  I use  $gte mongodb in run command geohaystack??

Basically I want to do the equivalent of

```
db.tablebusiness.find({ "LongitudeLatitude" : { "$nearSphere" : [106.772835, -6.186753], "$maxDistance" : 0.053980478460939611 }, "Prominent" : { "$gte" : 15 }, "indexContents" : { "$all" : [/^soto/, /^nasi/] } }).limit(200);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second query you specify

```
"Prominent" : {gte: 15}
```

whereas it should be

```
"Prominent" : { $gte : 15 }
```

Let me know if that was just a typo.

Comment: my programmer says both would work fine. I agree with you it shouldn't. Adding $ don't help though. I'll check again.